# Why .append() occurs multiple times despite I'm using .each()?

Tags: jquery, ruby, append, haml

I'm using jQuery for displaying dynamic content into panels of my page automatically. Each panel has a progress bar associated with a % number.

Note: this `progress-bar` is part of the `panels` I display. There's onyl one by `panel`

Here is a pic of the situation :
https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/26/2/1561482314-panel.jpg

I'm using `each()` and `append()` to add a div and inject content in it for every panels

The problem is that jQuery is creating as many div (which means it goes into my method and `append()`) as I display panels.

To be clear, if I display 10 panels, each `progress-bar` will have 10 children added with `.append` (so 9 extra that are obviously useless). You see them surrounded in red on the pic above

I can't understand why `each()` is not working

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.progress-bar').each(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    var barPercentage = t.data('percentage');
    var barContent = t.data('content');

    // add a div for the label text
    t.children('.label').append('<div class="label-text"></div>');

    // add some "gimme" percentage when data-percentage is <2
    if (parseInt((t.data('percentage')), 10) < 2) 
      barPercentage = 2;

    // set up the left/right label flipping
    if (barPercentage > 50) {
      t.children('.label').css("right", (100 - barPercentage) + '%');
      t.children('.label').css("margin-right", "-10px");
    }
  }
```

Also, here is my HTML :

```
  %div{class: "progress-bar", "data-percentage" => "#{number.to_i >= 100 ? '100' : number.to_i }", "data-content" => "#{label_content}", style:"background: white;"}
                    - if number.present?  &&  number.to_i != 0
                      %div{class: "bar", style: "background: #{color};"}
                        %span{style: "background: #{color};"}
                      %div{class: "label", style: "background: #{color}; border: 1px solid #{color}"}
//Here is where the "label-text" <div> is created with jQuery
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why .append occur multiple times despite I'm using .each?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758383/why-append-occur-multiple-times-despite-im-using-each)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is off-topic as it's a duplicate of one you asked yesterday. Please don't do that. Instead, re-edit your previous one if anything changed in the question. Asking multiple times don't improve your chance of answers, whereas improving the question will. "[What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers)" will help.